# Как вывести содержимое страницы WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Я в WP пока полный чайник. Поискал в гугле, как выводить содержимое страницы WordPress и написал вот такой код: https://hello-site.ru/share/vyvod-kontenta-wp/.

Проблема в том, что на страницу выводится не содержимое самой самой страницы, а содержимое записей. Подскажите, как вывести содержимое самой страницы.

Comment: Лучше не искать в гугле, а читать официальную документацию (https://developer.wordpress.org/), либо её некоторое подобие на русском (https://wp-kama.ru/), там по крайней мере меньше вероятность встретить вредные советы и некорректный/непонятный код

Answer (score 1):

Просто

```
the_content();
```

Вам это не нужно, если вы используете тему из репозитория. Там присутствуют все шаблоны страниц, и в нужном месте уже используется эта функция.

Но, судя по вопросу, вы начали изучение WP с написания собственной темы. Это большая ошибка.

Comment: Спасибо)Не за всё конечно, но спасибо)

Comment: Если ответ полезен, его стоит отметить как принятый галочкой внизу. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.

Comment: @PavelBogdanov а что вам не понравилось? Совет, основанный на опыте работы и на многочисленных ответах здесь? Да половина вопросов связана с тем, что люди, не имея достаточной квалификации, берутся за изготовление собственных тем (непонятно, зачем). И тонут в результате в собственных косяках. Моё дело предупредить - а там как хотите)